# How to populate listview with some specific data from SQLite ?? not whole

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, sms

In my SMS app for android, I don't want to show these SMS in native inbox and sent items. I have created a SQLite database for storing sent and received SMS as its a private app.

Sqlite database code :

```
protected static final String Table1=("CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLE_SMS+" ("
        + KEY_MESSAGEID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +SMS_Time+ " TEXT, "
        +PHONE_NUMBER+ " TEXT, "
        +MESSAGE_BODY+ " TEXT, "
        +FLAG+" TEXT);");  

public void Insert_sms_data(String formatedTime, String number, String body,String flag){
    try{

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SMS_Time, formatedTime);
        cv.put(PHONE_NUMBER, number);
        cv.put(MESSAGE_BODY, body);
        cv.put(FLAG, flag);
        DB.insert(TABLE_SMS, null, cv);
        DB.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR in insertion", ex.toString());
    }

}
public Cursor Return_All(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+"SMS_TABLE_RCV", null);
        return cur;

    }
```

SMS is received and stored in DB as follows:

```
flag = "0";
        DBmanager= new DbManager(context);
        DBmanager.open();
        DBmanager.Insert_sms_data(formatedTime ,number,body,flag);
        DBmanager.close();
```

Code for sending SMS and showing SMS in listview is as follows:

```
public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

private MyListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> item_id = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_time = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_flag = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
private Button btn_send;
DbManager manager;
Cursor Cursor;
ViewHolder holder12;
String contact_for_chat;
String contact_no;
String message_body = "";
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String time;
EditText et_chat;
String flag;
String msg = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    contact_for_chat = bundle.getString("contact_name");
    contact_for_chat = contact_for_chat.replace(" ", "");
    contact_no = Util.getContactNumber(contact_for_chat, ChatActivity.this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contact_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    manager = new DbManager(this);
    Cursor = manager.Return_All();
    showEvents(Cursor);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    setActionBar();
    findViewsById();
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SendSMS();
        }
    });
}

protected void SendSMS() {
    SmsManager sms_manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    message_body = et_chat.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms_manager.divideMessage(message_body);
    sms_manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(contact_no, null, parts, null, null);
    flag = "1";
    manager.Insert_sms_data(time, contact_no, message_body,flag);
    msg+= "SMS to :" + contact_for_chat + " \n";
    msg += "having number:" + contact_no + " \n";
    msg += "as" +message_body + " \n";
    msg += "at"+ time + " \n";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void setActionBar() {
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_chat, null);
    TextView tv_chat = (TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    tv_chat.setText(contact_for_chat);
    ColorDrawable colorDaawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CFCFC4"));
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDaawable);
    mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

private void findViewsById() {
    et_chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_chat);
    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
}

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {

    item_id = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_time = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_flag = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    int i=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        item_id.add(i+"");
        item_time.add(cursor.getString(1));
        item_msg_body.add(cursor.getString(3));
        item_phone_num.add(cursor.getString(2));
        item_flag.add(cursor.getString(4));
        i++;
    }

  }
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context con;
    private LayoutInflater layoutinf;
    ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<String> items_ = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyListAdapter(ChatActivity context) {
        con = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return item_id.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
            holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);

        }
                    else 
                    {
                        holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

                    }


        holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));


        holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));

        holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

        return v;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_contact;
    private TextView tv_sms_body;
    private TextView tv_time;

}
```

}

I retreive following result :

[image: result]
<sub>(source: [4shared.com](http://dc728.4shared.com/img/u4aArL8pce/s3/144ab8d92d0/device-2014-03-10-151709.png))</sub>

Contact no of Angelina is 5556 , but the list shows sms sent from other numbers as well, How can i poupulate my listview for only those specific contact numbers that are selecetd.
any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why you want us to visit the link when we can add image here directly ?

Comment: Change your query to: "SELECT * FROM SMS_TABLE_RCV WHERE " + PHONE_NUMBER + " = " + contact_no

Comment: i am new user so can't put image directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add where clause in your Return_all() function of your sqllite database code. Pass the value of where when you call return_all().

Like

public Cursor Return_All(Arraylist Where){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query= "where ";
    For(int i=0;i<where.size;i++)
    {
         query=query+"contact = "+where[i]+ " or "; }

   Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+"SMS_TABLE_RCV" + query , null);
    return cur; }
```

Comment: If i add where clause , then will it become specific to single contact? Actually i want to maintain listview for each and every user.i.e if (item_phone_num .contains(contact_no)) then retreive data.But its not working . The thing we see in native sms app and in whats app .

Comment: check my update answer you can pass the arraylist of selected contacts.

Comment: thanks vaibhav-ajay-gupta :) i have modified Cursor and its working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrayList use hashMap with key and value where key is contact number and value is message then you can differentiate between the users using key values